# Как через WP_Query вывести похожий товар?

Tags: woocommerce

Как через WP_Qurey вывести похожий товар из категории?

Comment: И каковы критерии "похожести"?

Comment: Критерий только - товар данной категории и все, так можно абсолютно рандом

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, вы хотите вывести 4 случайных товара из категории со слагом `category-slug`. Код такой:

```
$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'category-slug',
        ),
    ),
);

$q = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Ну и дальше стандартный цикл.